# Product Visibility preventing coupon code

Tags: promotions, enterprise-1.14

I (someone I am working with) have a magento store ( well you already know that or I won't be posting here ).

I have set up few products and few promotions. Some of the products have catalog and search visibility while other products have no visibility. When a customer adds an item which has catalog and search scope ( vis ) the promotion works fine; but if the customer chooses product with no visibility the promotion is not recognized.

Have any of you faced similar problem in past? Any productive reply is welcomed.

Thanks in Advance,

Answer (score 0):

In Magento, cart works on visible products in frontend. If you want to work with invisible product, you need to customize a lot.
You can also work with main product if this product is sub product of configurable product or bundled product.

Comment: Thank you MageComp. I would appreciate if you point any link to some resource or tutorial for customization.